# rescue in filesystem_access': Bundler::Dsl::DSLError in ruby rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, project, new-operator, idangero

when I create new rails new project, when bundle install give me this error

> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:117:in
>   `rescue in filesystem_access': Bundler::Dsl::DSLError

Comment: I m using Windows 10 pro

Comment: before create rails project I downlaod git and node js

Comment: `Bundler.with_clean_env` has been deprecated in favor of `Bundler.with_unbundled_env`. If you instead want the environment before bundler was originally loaded, use `Bundler.with_original_env` (called at C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:385)
and also this error when create a project

Comment: Please take the [tour]. You seem to be unaware of several basic ideas of StackOverflow and the information provided there might help you a lot.